# Passing string value between the jframe in java

Tags: java, netbeans

How can I pass string values between jframe  without using textfield.

Comment: Are you asking: are there any other ways of getting input from `JFrame` besides `JTextField`?

Comment: Yes, i want to transfer string value. I don't need any text field.

Comment: where are you transferring string values?

Comment: Inside public frame(){    }, or accessible wherever I like.